# Higher expected value and same variance implies weak dominance?

Tags: portfolio-management

In his book *Risk and Asset Allocation*, Meucci [writes](http://www.symmys.com/sites/default/files/Risk%20and%20Asset%20Allocation%20-%20Springer%20Quantitative%20Finance%20-%20Optimization_0.pdf#page=19) (last paragraph)

> Indeed, since all the indices of satisfaction $\mathcal{S}$ discussed
>   in Chapter 5 are consistent with weak stochastic dominance, for a
>   given level of variance of the objective, higher expected values of
>   the objective are always appreciated, no matter the functional
>   expression of $\tilde{\mathcal{H}}$.

I'm trying to figure out the mathematical content/proof behind this statement. The context:

Let $\mathbf{M} : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a random vector, $\mathbf{\alpha} \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Define a random variable $\mathbf{\Psi}_\mathbf{\alpha} = \mathbf{\alpha}^T \mathbf{M}$, the *objective*.

Let $\mathcal{S}(\mathbf{\alpha}) = \tilde{\mathcal{H}}(\mathrm{E}\{\mathbf{\Psi}_\mathbf{\alpha}\}, \mathrm{Var}\{\mathbf{\Psi}_\mathbf{\alpha}\})$, the *index of satisfaction*.

Moreover assume that $\mathcal{S}$ is consistent with weak stochastic dominance, ie.

$$\mathbf{\Psi}_\mathbf{\alpha} \leq_{\mathrm{weak}} \mathbf{\Psi}_\mathbf{\beta} \Rightarrow \mathcal{S}(\mathbf{a}) \leq \mathcal{S}(\mathbf{b})$$

I feel that Meucci is saying that if $\mathrm{Var}\{\mathbf{\Psi}_\mathbf{\alpha}\} = \mathrm{Var}\{\mathbf{\Psi}_\mathbf{\beta}\}$ and $\mathrm{E}\{\mathbf{\Psi}_\mathbf{\alpha}\} \leq \mathrm{E}\{\mathbf{\Psi}_\mathbf{\beta}\}$ then $\mathbf{\Psi}_\mathbf{\alpha} \leq_{\mathrm{weak}} \mathbf{\Psi}_\mathbf{\beta}$. But this isn't true.

Comment: Can you remind me of the definition of the weak stochastic dominance? Is that one CDF dominates another?

Comment: @Ulysses: yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the author has assumed the approximation (6.67)
$$\mathcal{S}(\alpha)\approx   \tilde{\mathcal{H}} (\mathrm{E}\{\Phi_\alpha\},\mathrm{Var}\{\Phi_\alpha\})$$
That is, the index of satisfaction $\mathcal{S}(\alpha)$ depends only on
the first two moments of the marginals. As explained by the author in section
6.5.1, this is a good approximation because in a wide range of applications,
the market $\mathbf M$ is *[elliptically distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptical_distribution)*
(see (6.126)).

One important example is 
$$
\mathbf{M}\sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol\mu,\,\boldsymbol\Sigma)
$$
where $\mathcal{N}$ is the [*multivariate* Gaussian distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution)
with mean $\boldsymbol \mu$ and covariance matrix $\boldsymbol \Sigma$. In
this case, if $\mathrm{Var}(\boldsymbol \Psi_\alpha)=\mathrm{Var}(\boldsymbol\Psi_\beta)$
and $\mathrm{E}[\boldsymbol \Psi_\alpha]\le\mathrm{E}[\boldsymbol\Psi_\beta]$,
then indeed we have weak stochastic dominance, i.e. for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$,
$$ 
P\{\boldsymbol\Psi_\alpha\le t\}=\int_{-\infty}^t \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\,
e^{-\frac{(x - \mu_1)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}dx\ge\int_{-\infty}^t\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\,
e^{-\frac{(x - \mu_2)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}dx= P\{\boldsymbol\Psi_\beta\le t\}
$$
where $\sigma^2=\mathrm{Var}(\boldsymbol \Psi_\alpha)=\mathrm{Var}(\boldsymbol\Psi_\beta)=\boldsymbol\alpha^T\boldsymbol
\Sigma\boldsymbol\alpha=  \boldsymbol\beta^T\boldsymbol \Sigma \boldsymbol
\beta$, $\mu_1=\mathrm{E}[\boldsymbol \Psi_\alpha]=\boldsymbol \alpha^T\mathrm{E}[\boldsymbol\Psi]$,
and $\mu_2=\mathrm{E}[\boldsymbol \Psi_\beta]=\boldsymbol \beta^T\mathrm{E}[\boldsymbol\Psi]$. (Recall that we say $\boldsymbol \Psi_\alpha\le_{\mathrm{weak}} \boldsymbol \Psi_\beta$ if $$P\{\boldsymbol\Psi_\alpha\le t\}\ge P\{\boldsymbol\Psi_\beta\le t\}$$ — the inequality is reversed — see (5.35).)

The reasoning for a general elliptic distribution is similar. 
We will show that
the distribution functions of  $\boldsymbol \Psi_\alpha$ and $\boldsymbol
\Psi_\beta$ are translates of each other.  Since $\mathbf{M}  $ is elliptically
distributed, its characteristic function  $\varphi_{\mathbf{M } }$ is of
the form 
$$
\varphi_{\mathbf{M } }( \boldsymbol t) =  e^{i \boldsymbol t^T\boldsymbol\mu}
\chi(\boldsymbol t^T\boldsymbol\Sigma
\boldsymbol t)
$$for some  $\boldsymbol\mu \in \mathbb{R}^N$,
positive-definite matrix $\boldsymbol\Sigma$, and characteristic function
$\chi$. Hence, for any $\boldsymbol \alpha \in \mathbb{R}^N$, the characteristic
function $\varphi_{\boldsymbol \Psi_\alpha}$ of  $\boldsymbol \Psi_\alpha=\boldsymbol\alpha^T
\mathbf{M}$ is
$$
\varphi_{\boldsymbol
\Psi_\alpha}(t)=\varphi_{\mathbf{M } }(t\boldsymbol\alpha)=  e^{it\boldsymbol
\alpha^T\boldsymbol\mu} \chi(t^2 \boldsymbol\alpha^T\boldsymbol\Sigma \boldsymbol
\alpha) 
$$ 
After calculating the derivatives of  $\varphi_{\boldsymbol
\Psi_\alpha}$, we find that 
$$
E[\boldsymbol\Psi_\alpha ] =\boldsymbol\alpha^T\boldsymbol\mu 
$$
and 
$$
\mathrm{Var}(\boldsymbol\Psi_\alpha)=2\boldsymbol\alpha^T \boldsymbol\Sigma
\boldsymbol\alpha\chi
   '(0)   
$$
Thus, if $\mathrm{Var}(\boldsymbol\Psi_\alpha)=\mathrm{Var}(\boldsymbol\Psi_\beta)$,
then $\boldsymbol\alpha^T \boldsymbol\Sigma
\boldsymbol\alpha=\boldsymbol\beta^T \boldsymbol\Sigma\boldsymbol\beta$.
Therefore,   $$
  \varphi_{\boldsymbol
\Psi_\beta}(t) =e^{it(\boldsymbol \beta^T\boldsymbol\mu-\boldsymbol \alpha^T\boldsymbol\mu)}\varphi_{\boldsymbol
\Psi_\alpha}(t) 
$$which implies that
$$
f_{\boldsymbol
\Psi_\beta}(x)=f_{\boldsymbol
\Psi_\alpha}(x-(\boldsymbol \beta^T\boldsymbol\mu-\boldsymbol \alpha^T\boldsymbol\mu))
$$that is, the density functions $f_{\boldsymbol
\Psi_\alpha}$ and $f_{\boldsymbol
\Psi_\beta}$ are translates of each other. Since $\boldsymbol \beta^T\boldsymbol\mu-\boldsymbol
\alpha^T\boldsymbol\mu=E[\boldsymbol\Psi_\beta ]-E[\boldsymbol\Psi_\alpha
]\ge0$ by assumption, we have shown that $\boldsymbol\Psi_\alpha\le_{\mathrm{weak}}\boldsymbol\Psi_\beta
$.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. In an earlier paragraph Meucci says

> Suppose that we can focus on the two first moments only and neglect
>   all the higher moments.

So two random variables are equivalent if their first two moments agree. Therefore any random variable can be replaced by $\mathcal{U}(\mu - \sqrt{3}\sigma, \mu + \sqrt{3}\sigma)$ as far as $\mathcal{S}$ is concerned.

By looking at the cdf below, it is clear that
$$\mathcal{U}(\mu_1 - \sqrt{3}\sigma, \mu_1 + \sqrt{3}\sigma) \leq_\mathrm{weak} \mathcal{U}(\mu_2 - \sqrt{3}\sigma, \mu_2 + \sqrt{3}\sigma)$$
when $\mu_1 \leq \mu_2$.

[image]